# Django | Get count of articles per month

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm, django-annotate

I got two models **Article** and **Author** implemented like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
```

On my template I want to plot a graph (using chart.js on the frontend side) showing the authors publications per month, for the last 12 months. For that I need the count of articles published each month.

This is the query to get the authors articles:

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(author=author)
```

###### What would be best practice to get the count per month?

I've thought about annotating each of the twelve month separately to the QuerySet, but haven't found a way that works for me.
Alternatively, I thought about dealing with this on the JS site in the users browser.

Any suggestions/recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to group data in Django you'll need to use [ORM aggregation features](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation).

And to use that on dates you can leverage their [ORM helper functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncMonth).

```py
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
from django.db.models import Count

Article.objects
    .filter(author=author)                 # Filter by the author   
    .annotate(month=TruncMonth('created')) # Truncate by month and add 'month' to values
    .values('month')                       # Group By month
    .annotate(count_id=Count('id'))        # Count the number of articles in the grouping
    .order_by('-month')[:12]               # Sort by months in descending order (latest to earliest) and get the 12 first results
```